# How do i prevent jenkins from single quoting the parameterized value

Tags: jenkins

I have string parameter param1.If i try to build the job with param1=[a] and using $param1, jenkins adds single quote like 'param1=[a]'.How do i get rid of single quotes?

Comment: Please provide more details: In which context you think Jenkins adds single quotes? In a shell build step? Or something else? How did you verify single quotes were added? Can you provide an example, a screenshot or log?

Answer (score 4):

This has **absolutely nothing** to do with Jenkins. The problem is that you expect whatever the value of the variable is to effectively be put where you reference the variable in the shell, and `bash` just doesn't work that way. Some characters have special meaning *on the command line (only)*, unless escaped, such as `"`, or `;` (which separated individual commands on the same line).

You'll see that the double quotation marks are actually part of the variable value when you run `env` in your shell build step. So Jenkins does everything right -- it passes the argument onto the shell build step verbatim, as environment variable.

The single quotation marks are added *by the shell* in its echoing the effective command so you can just copy it and get the same behavior when pasting it into a shell.

---

A possible solution here is to use `eval` instead – it behaves as if the arguments were written on a command line and executes them. Of course **this can be dangerous** if you allow users who aren't fully trusted to provide arguments to this Jenkins job.

```
$ VAR="you fool ; pwd"
$ echo $VAR
you fool ; pwd
$ eval echo $VAR
you fool
/Users/danielbeck
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `sh` build step in Jenkins' groovy/pipeline context, and you simply want variable substitution instead of passing the variable via the bash environment, what you can do is force the substitution prior to passing the command to `sh` with a `.toString()`.  For example:

`sh("some command ${param1}".toString())`